# Statistical function which computes the average work time in different months

Tags: beginner, ruby, statistics

It's a task from a Ruby-course, in which I'm currently enrolled:
[Ruby Course - Page](https://open.hpi.de/courses/ruby2018/items/5AKyBqWnJw9dLP7xQdImmj)

Precisely it's one of the assignments for the first week.

Following idea:
Your are given a list in which finished work-tasks are logged.
`[
  {work: "item 1", date: "2017-04-26", time: 20},
  {work: "item 2", date: "2017-04-27", time: 27},
  ...`

You shall write a function which computes the daily work-time for the different months.
Means: The average daily work-time in April, avg. time in May, ... in June. And so on ...

A data-structure, to work upon, was given. Even the result, which is expected for that data-structure: `{ "2017-04" => 40, "2017-05" => 14 }`.

I was able to write a function, which passed all unit-tests.
Here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
tasks = [
  {work: "item 1", date: "2017-04-26", time: 20},
  {work: "item 2", date: "2017-04-27", time: 27},
  {work: "item 3", date: "2017-04-27", time: 33},
  {work: "item 4", date: "2017-05-05", time: 20},
  {work: "item 5", date: "2017-05-06", time: 12},
  {work: "item 6", date: "2017-05-14", time: 10},
]

# Expected result : { "2017-04" => 40, "2017-05" => 14 }
def work_per_month(tasks)
  days_aggregate = {}

  tasks.each do | task |
    key = task[:date]

    if days_aggregate.key?(key)
      days_aggregate[key][0] = days_aggregate[key][0] + task[:time]
    else
      arr = []
      arr[0] = task[:time]

      days_aggregate[key] = arr
    end
  end

  months_aggregate = {}

  days_aggregate.each do | key, task |
    parts = key.split("-")
    k = "#{parts[0]}-#{parts[1]}"

    if months_aggregate.key?(k)
      months_aggregate[k][0] = months_aggregate[k][0] + task[0]
      months_aggregate[k][1] = months_aggregate[k][1] + 1
    else
      arr = []
      arr[0] = task[0]
      arr[1] = 1

      months_aggregate[k] = arr
    end
  end

  avg_hours_month = {}

  months_aggregate.each do | key, data |
    avg_hours_month[key] = data[0] / data[1]
  end

  avg_hours_month
end

puts work_per_month(tasks)  # Returns {"2017-04"=>40, "2017-05"=>14}
```

Please take into account that I started Ruby programming just a week ago.

It works and it has passed the tests. But I'm aware that it is clumsy.

**Is there are more elegant way to solve the described task?**

Without having this sequence of loops?

Comment: The example result seems wrong: the average of `(20 + 27 + 33) / 3` is `26.666..`, not `40`. Now, I don't know about elegant, especially for the first week (!), but `tasks.group_by {|h| h[:date][0..6]}.reduce({}) {|out, (k, v)| out[k] = v.reduce(0.0) {|sum, h| sum + h[:time] } / v.size; out}` should do it as a one-liner. Not that it should be a one-liner, reason here is just so it fits in a comment box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Rubocop Report

[Rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop) was able to solve minor layout issues regarding the use of white spaces. One note-worthy change it proposed is:

- [Corrected] Style/StringLiterals: Prefer single-quoted strings when you don't need string interpolation or special symbols.

> ```
> days_aggregate.each do | key, task |
>   parts = key.split("-")
> ```

```
 parts = key.split('-')
```

A bigger complexity issue it found was:

- Metrics/AbcSize: Assignment Branch Condition size for work_per_month is too high. [33/15]
- Metrics/MethodLength: Method has too many lines. [30/10]

This means your method `work_per_month` is doing way too much. It has more than double the [AbcSize](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.27.0/RuboCop/Cop/Metrics/AbcSize) than the suggested threshold `[33/15]`. You should split this method in sub-routines.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You are of course right. 41 lines is indeed too much. Normally it should be 30 lines maximal.

Comment: The default is set even lower than 30: it's 10 https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_metrics/